# Current source load mosfet

Tags: mosfet, analog, nmos

[image]

Guys I have a silly doubt. above is a standard circuit. I wish to ask how can a small signal current exist through the transistor shown above? The current source ( which is dc) will always force the saturation cureent of nmos to be = I<sub>D</sub>. So how can there be a situation of small signal analysis of nmos? As far I understand i<sub>D</sub> = I<sub>D</sub> + i<sub>d</sub>, where second order distortion is neglected. So i<sub>d</sub> (the ac component) will always be forced to be zero because of current source right??

Comment: this is circuit of basic gain cell

Comment: You have a load connected to Vo in a practical circuit, right?  What's the load impedance and what does that do to the current?

Answer (score 2):

The circuit shown above even works with an ideal current source. The reason is that the NMOS transistor has an output resistance, which is often called rds. A small voltage at the input of the NMOS will cause a current id which is given by id=Vi * gm. The output resistance will convert this current back into a voltage Vo = -id * rds = -Vi * gm * rds.

It is now easy to see that the gain of the circuit is Vo/Vi = -gm*rds.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you're missing is that the current source shown is NOT an "ideal" source like the ones you talk about in theory class — one that has the same current regardless of the voltage (positive or negative) across it.

Instead, we're talking about a practical current source that works over a limited voltage range. If the transistor can't pass all of the current that the source is designed for, the voltage across the current source will drop to a level at which it stops working. In other words, you can think of it more as a current limiter than a current source.

Answer (score 0):

Taking what you have shown exactly, you can definitely get small signal behavior from it by biasing the input (Vgs) accordingly. The NMOS will operate like a variable resistor therefore the output voltage will change even with constant Id.

But such a circuit by itself as shown would be finicky to work with. The Rds to Vgs relationship is non-linear and is quite variable (due to device samples, temperature, etc).